# How can I display all tools for Kendo Editor and prevent them to push to Overflow Anchor?

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-editor

I have a Kendo Jquery Editor with a lot of tools.  I need to show all the tools inside the editor regardless of the available space in the toolbar.  I need the ones that don't fit in the first line to go to the second/next line instead of being pushed into the Overflow Anchor.  Currently, any tool that doesn't fit into the space gets pushed to the "more tools" menu.

Sample code:

```
 $("#editor").kendoEditor({
            tools: [
                "bold",
                "italic",
                "underline",
                "strikethrough",
                "justifyLeft",
                "justifyCenter",
                "justifyRight",
                "justifyFull",
                "insertUnorderedList",
                "insertOrderedList",
                ........
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you maybe have `resizable.toolbar` set to true?

> `resizable.toolbar` **Boolean**
>
> If `resizable` is `set` to true the widget will detect changes in the viewport width and will >hide the overflowing controls in the tool overflow popup.

Documentation: [resizable.toolbar](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/editor/configuration/resizable.toolbar#resizabletoolbar)

Try to set it on false:

```
$("#editor").kendoEditor({
  resizable: {
      toolbar: false
  }
});
```